# Difference between Registrant and Controller of .eth domain?

Tags: eth-domain

Usually the **registrant** and **controller** are the same for .eth domains, meaning the same Ethereum address appears in both fields, so what does it mean when they are different?

[image]

Finally, what or who is  the **Resolver**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Registrant**: Address to which the domain is registered. Has overall control.

**Controller**: If not the registrant, then an address to which the registrant has delegated day-to-day control over the domain. (For example, a company could register a domain with a set of subdomains, and delegate each subdomain to a different controller in a different group in the company.)

**Resolver**: Address of the contract which resolves the `.eth` domain to the associated set of records (which among other things can include, e.g., a wallet address).

Comment: would the Controller also handle automated renewal of the domain?

Comment: Good question. I was under the impression that _anyone_ could renew the domain on behalf of the original registrant (meaning it would still remain registered to that registrant). This would allow a subdomain controller to ensure that their subdomain continues to exist even if the original registrant disappears/dies/etc.

Comment: With regards to automation - I didn't think there was any. You can pay for the registration for years in advance, but once those years are up, you'd have to renew again.

Comment: Okay, see Yearly Rent section here: https://medium.com/the-ethereum-name-service/ens-is-upgrading-heres-what-you-need-to-do-f26423339fcf

Comment: is it true that the difference between DNS renewal, is that, with ENS renewal, there pretty much is no sunk cost in holding an .eth domain name in that, even if you buy an .eth domain for 1 yr, 2 yrs or 10 yrs, you lock in the registration fee up-front for that length of time but you will be returned it in full when you decide to stop renewing?

Comment: That's how it originally worked, yes. However, things changed (I think at the end of 2019, exactly for the reason you're getting at) meaning that you effectively now have to pay non-refundable rent.